# My local API 127.0.0.1:8000 doesn't work with docker

Tags: django, docker

I have simple django project with one html page and I try to deploy it with docker. My Dockerfile you can see below:

```
FROM python:3.10.9

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I run my image with next command:
`docker run -p 8000:8000 --rm 751aa7a2d66f`

But when I open my browser the localhost with API 127.0.0.1:8000 doesn't work.
In the same time I run command `docker ps` and it shows the following:
[docker ps result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftbnd.png)

What's the problem?
Thanks in advance for your help.
For your information I work on windows 7.

I tried to run `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000 --rm 751aa7a2d66f` but it didn't help.
I also tried to change port of my local machine to 8001 with the same result.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what happens?  What variety of Docker are you using?  Does `docker ps` actually write out a PNG file?

Comment: what output do you get on "127.0.0.1:8000"  do you see something in the logs of the container?

Comment: It would help a lot if you also include the logs of the container. you can get it with:
`docker logs [YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME]`. most probably your app has not started properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can run django with docker-compose.yml below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_django_service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have already resolved this problem. I just had to use IP address of virtual machine where is the docker instead localhost (127.0.0.1).
I think it is the feature of docker virtualbox. I work on windows 7 so I can use only docker virtualbox.